# Is there a way to make marks in color or at least visible?

Tags: mark

Is there a way to make marks in color or at least visible?

Actually I need to put visible marks on the text (code) in Vim.

Comment: Do you need to make `mark`s visible or do you need to put visible marks in your editor window? If the latter, `:h :sign` may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the plugin [vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature) to see the marks in the margin:

[image: vim-signature screenshot]

Comment: I stumbled upon it but saw the last commit was in 2018. Thank you for verifying it's still working.

Comment: I'm using it every day. I confirm it is working fine :-)